# Convert ng-click code to react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this following button with `ng-click`

```
<button ng-click="productClass.saveProductMehod()">Save</button>
```

and i try to convert it to React

```
<button-component on-submit="productClass.saveProductMehod"
   value="'Save'"></button-component>
```

with

```
class ButtonComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.props.onSubmit();
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
            {this.props.value}
        </button>
    );
  }
}

ButtonComponent.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export { ButtonComponent }
```

ProductClass

```
class ProductClass {
   saveProductMehod() {
      this.submitted = true;
      //save the product
   }
}
```

The problem here is when the i click the button i loose `this` initialization from constructor of the `ProductClass` and when it gets in the `saveProductMethod` the this is the props object. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few pieces missing here:

```
<button-component on-submit="productClass.saveProductMehod"
   value="'Save'"></button-component>
```

Should be (noting the quotes around save and the quotes onSubmit, as well as the case):

```
<ButtonComponent onSubmit={productClass.saveProductMehod}
   value="Save"></ButtonComponent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume your angular ng-click to be:

```
<button ng-click="onClick()">Save</button>
```

**Analogous React Component (Stateless Form) would be:**

```
const ReactButton = props =>(<button onClick={props.onClick} value={props.value}/>)
```

**Analogous React Component (Class Based Form) would be:**

```
class ReactButton extends React.Component{
 render(){
   return(<button 
             onClick={this.props.onClick} 
             value={this.props.value}/>)
 }
}
```

Usage of this ReactButton:

Thats it!

**Important Points to keep in mind:**

1. Custom Component follow convention that they start with Capital
   Alphabet and follow camel case syntax.
2. JSX is just like html. Only class -> className.
3. Every Component Name should be a valid JS variable

Answer (score 0):

The new method must be binded to the controller in order to have access to predefined attributes:

```
this.saveProductMehod = this.saveProductMehod.bind(this);
```